# How to create a SOAP Request C#

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap, wsdl

I know there are thousands of step-by-step samples for consuming a SOAP project with C#.
Actually, I tried many of those but didn't really get to understand how it works, how were needed components built or how to integrate a certificate for a secure connection. 
I would be really grateful if any of you guys have a magical resource, since I read somewhere I shouldn't do it this way or another, I really want to know this well.

Thank you, 
Best regards.

Comment: First question: Do you have a web service to consume? Does it need certificate auth? Cause most of the tutorial assume that you have a service or build a basic one without any kind of auth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really simple actually. Suppose you have a service at http://myhost.com/XService.svc - right click References in the solution explorer and choose "Add a service reference" (older versions of VS called it web reference/web service)

A wizard appears; pop your URL into it, set a few options and hit Go

You'll get a client class set created that references the service, with methods that take a set of typed parameters based on what the service said it wanted when VS queried its WSDL. You might use it like:

```
var c = new XServiceClient();

bool result = c.CreateNewPerson("John Smith", 30, "js@hotmail.com");
```

The service client handles all of the xml creation, tcp socket connection, data transmission etc necessary to pass those 3 values you sent, to the web service so that the relevant method is called, the response is returned etc